# Is there such a thing as a CONSTANT in SQL Server that I can refer to in different stored procedures in my database?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have this code which is part of a stored procedure. I have other stored procedures with similar snippets.

```
    INSERT INTO dbo.UserTest
    (  
        AdminTestId,
        Sequence,
        TestStatusId              
    ) 
    VALUES
    (
        @AdminTestId,
        @SEQ ,
        1
    )
```

Now I just realized the value of `1` should be a `2` for the testStatusId. I keep making these mistakes as I forget which number is which.

Is there some way that I can have a constant that I could reference that would be set in one place outside all of the stored procedures?

Ideally what I would like to do is something like this. But I don't want to declare the value of TestStatusId.Started at the top of every stored procedure.

```
    INSERT INTO dbo.UserTest
    (  
        AdminTestId,
        Sequence,
        TestStatusId              
    ) 
    VALUES
    (
        @AdminTestId,
        @SEQ ,
        @TestStatsusId.Started
    )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no concept of a *constant* in the context of a global value that can be referenced in your stored procedures. You can declare variables (although not constant) within your stored procedures: `DECLARE @variableName <VariableType> = <Value>`, but not outside of them.

The best option for having access to a value across multiple database objects is to create a table that contains your global values. In your stored procedure, you can then use a `SELECT` statement to retrieve the value for you or create a user-defined function that pulls back a value by some key (e.g. by name).

Answer (score 1):

There aren't 'constants' in the typical programming sense, but you're working in a database; your tables are filled with constants.  If this is an issue for you, you could have a table that has the numeric identifier in one column and a keyword representation in the other.  Alternatively, you could have a function that does this conversion for you, and call it in the stored procedure.